# whats the complexity of this program is it n^2*logn or what?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```py
lst=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))
def median(x):
    x=sorted(x)
    mid=len(x)//2
    
    if(len(x)%2==0):
        return (x[mid-1]+x[mid])/2
    return x[mid]
medlist=[]
for i in range(1,len(lst)+1):
    a=median(lst[:i])
    print(a)
    medlist.append(a)
medlist
```

whats the time complexity of this program is it **n^2*log(n)** or something else?

Comment: Yes; why do you think it might not be?

Comment: i dont know i am just learning so want to confirm weather i have calculated it right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can break it down like this:

```
for i in range(1,len(lst)+1):
    ....
```

this does whatever is in the forloop n times.  So we already know that running time will be `O(n x whatever is in the forloop)`

Analyzing the forloop we see some constant operations and a call to `median`.  Now the size of what is called to median is important.  Here it is `1,2,3,4,....,n` in length. On average this is `n/2`, so we can say it is `O(n)` in in size.

Analyzing the median function we see that it is sorting, which we know to be `O(n log n)` plus a couple of constant operations.   So we can say that the median function is of `O(n log n)`.

Plugging this into the first function, we see that the order is `O(n*n log n)` or `O(n^2 log n)`